# Trying to set Multioptions in ZF form 1.12, identical arraystructure, one works the other won't work why?

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form

I am trying to populate a select list (`Zend_Form_Element_Select`) and i have these two arrays i tried. (These are var dumps)

This one works:

```
array(2) {
  [0] => array(2) {
    ["key"] => int(1)
    ["value"] => string(4) "Test"
  }
  [1] => array(2) {
    ["key"] => int(2)
    ["value"] => string(5) "Test2"
}
```

This one doesn't:

```
array(3) {
  [0] => array(2) {
    ["key"] => int(1)
    ["value"] => string(16) "Test Kategorie 1"
  }
  [1] => array(2) {
    ["key"] => int(2)
    ["value"] => string(16) "Test Kategorie 2"
  }
  [2] => array(2) {
    ["key"] => int(3)
    ["value"] => string(4) "rene"
  }
}
```

This is a snippet of my code:

```
$select = new Zend_Form_Element_Select('video_category', array(
      'required'      => true,
      'label'         => 'label_video_category',
    //'multioptions'    => $this->categories,
      'description'   => 'text_video_category',
      'class'         => 'input',
      'id'          => 'select_video_category'
));
$options =  array(
            array(  'key'   => 1, 
                    'value' => 'Test'),
            array(  'key'   => 2,
                    'value' => 'Test2'),
         );
Zend_Debug::dump($options);
$select->addMultioptions($this->categories);
$this->addElement($select);
```

So if anybody has any clue for me, i'd be very thankful, because i'm stuck with this for hours now...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using *$this->categories* in *addMultioptions*. Just verify if you are assigning the options to this variable.

```
     $this->categories = $options;
```

The following code worked for me for both the arrays:

```
      $form = new Zend_Form();
      $select = new Zend_Form_Element_Select('video_category', array(
                 'required'      => true,
                 'label'         => 'label_video_category',
                  'description'   => 'text_video_category',
                  'class'         => 'input',
                 'id'          => 'select_video_category'
    ));

    $select->addMultioptions($this->categories);
$form->addElement($select);
```

Arrays used:

```
   $options =  array(
        array(  'key'   => 1, 
                'value' => 'Test'),
        array(  'key'   => 2,
                'value' => 'Test2'),
     );

   $options = array(
    array(  'key'   => 1, 
                'value' => 'Test Kategorie 1'),
    array(  'key'   => 2,
                'value' => 'Test Kategorie 2'),
    array(  'key'   => 3,
                'value' => 'rene')
    );
```

Comment: Hey thanks alot for your Time. I found the error and it wasn't in my code but rather in db and file encodings...